# strange input type="file" not working on a computer using IE

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, input

I have a very strange problem that I cannot solve.

There is something preventing a user from opening the file browse window when clicking the browse button in internet explorer. This input does not use javascript. I am unable to access the user's computer to see what is happening on their end.

They are using MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.0

```
 <input name="picture" type="file" width="100px" class="stretch">
```

If anyone has any ideas why the input is not working I would greatly appreciate them.

Comment: Nothing on your website could prevent a *single* user from not being able to use the file input. It is obviously something wrong with either their OS or browser. That HTML is perfectly accurate, aside from the width attribute.

Comment: @animuson that was my initial thought, but I would rather exhaust all possibilities here before coming to that conclusion. Do you know if there is a setting in IE that prevents the browse dialog box from opening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Html looks good, i have tryed it. I think the only thing that breaks the functionality is your css-class "stretch". Please try it without that css class and/or post the style definition here.

Comment: I removed the class, now I just have to wait for the user to test it and see if it helped.